# How can I retrieve the column names in Google Cloud-SQL when accessing MySQL with Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-sql

I perform this kind of query in my Python code to

```
conn = rdbms.connect(instance=_INSTANCE_NAME, database='tiger')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from terminals")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

After this I call a Jinja2 template, to which I pass the rows variable, which I can successullfy use there in a `{% for row in rows %}` code.

I could not find out how I can get the name of the columns. I tried to get it out of the rows variable, but in vain. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you execute your SQL query, try reading from the property `cursor.description`

With the MySQLdb module (not sure if you can use that specific module with Google Cloud-SQL), the `.description` will be a tuple of tuples, like ((field1_name, ...), (field2_name, ...), ...)

I hope that solves your problem.  Best wishes for your project and happy coding!